How to incorporate Prisma Migration in docker compose run the entire app in one command?
Main Issue: Not being able to incorporate prisma migration in docker compose.
I have a full stack project which I want to run within docker container. The backend has postgres integrated via Prisma ORM. So, the folder structure looks somewhat like the following:

fullstack-app/
  backend/
    backend.dockerfile
    ...
  frontend/
    frontend.dockerfile
    ...
  compose.yaml

backend.dockerfile: 
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY prisma ./prisma

RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]

frontend.dockerfile: not attaching since I just pasted it from the guideline of next.js with docker. It doesn't have any issue, works perfectly fine.
compose.yaml: 
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:4000
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres?schema=public
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

I want to add npx prisma migrate dev --name init command in backend service so that when I run docker compose up -d command, prisma migration takes place before backend getting run in its container.
I have tried healthcheck mechanism but it gets me error and backend doesn't get run.
So, overall my question is how could I incorporate npx prisma migrate dev --name init command so that I get the entire full stack app containerized in one command which is docker compose up -d ?
Actually I want anyone to get to run the app if that person has docker installed, without having to install any package or anything.
More Detail: If you want to see the entire code you could see Francesco Ciulla's Blog Post. There he did the same thing with docker but he ran separate commands to containerize each service and he also ran prisma migration command separately. But in my case I want it in one command, I don't want to run prisma migration separately.

Just spitballing here, but you could add that migrate script to your backend Dockerfile and in your compose file make your backend service depend on your db service.

I tend to recommend running migrations and other startup-time steps in an entrypoint wrapper script; the linked question has a specific example here.
